# Adding many points to a personalized Google map

Tags: google-maps

I wish to create a personalized google map (as is shown [here](http://earth.google.com/outreach/tutorial_mymaps.html)),

I see it is possible to import a geo file (KML, KMZ or GeoRSS) with many points. I would love to use that but don't know how to create such a geo file in the first place.

Which one should I use? What is the best way to create them?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned in Gnoupi's answer, you can export from [Google Earth](http://earth.google.com/). You can also create them directly in the browser though. Log in to your Google account, then go to [Google Maps](http://maps.google.com/), and click on "My Maps". Then click "create new map".

[image: "Google Maps - create new map" screenshot]

You can then enter a title and description, and start adding points and lines to the map using the buttons on the upper left hand corner of the map area. Click on the balloon, then drop it anywhere on the map. You can also search for a location, then click on a result and choose "Save to..." to add it to one of your saved maps. You can also set up sharing so that other Google users you authorize can add to the map, using the "collaborate" link.

[image: buttons]

[image: save location]

Answer (score 1):

[Google Earth](http://earth.google.com/) allows you to create such files. You can mark several locations, and save a folder with all of them as a kml or kmz file.

Also, [here is the documentation](http://code.google.com/apis/kml/documentation/whatiskml.html) from Google about kml files.